# Save vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygonal attribute with hibernate 5

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to upgrade an older Project to **spring/hibernate 5**. We use the `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygonal` library on some entites to store shape data in our **Oracle** DB(19c). The configured hibernate dialect is `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect`.

With the previous hibernate Version this worked:

```
@XmlTransient
@Column(name = GEOMETRY_COLUMN_NAME)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Polygonal shape;
```

I tried different types with hibernate 5 but i can never flush the entity to the DB. it crashes in our abstract save method:

```
    public T save(T entity) {
        Serializable pk = (Serializable) ((IdentificationInformation) entity).getPk();
        try {
               getEntityManager().persist(entity);
               getEntityManager().flush(); 
               getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
            }
```

The stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3297) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3824) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    ... 185 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: Inkonsistente Datentypen: MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY erwartet, BINARY erhalten

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:910) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3865) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3845) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:136) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:136) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:9.0.38]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor457.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper.doExecute(JdbcWrapper.java:403) ~[javamelody-core-1.53.0.jar:1.53.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$StatementInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:128) ~[javamelody-core-1.53.0.jar:1.53.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285) ~[javamelody-core-1.53.0.jar:1.53.0]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
    ... 196 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00932: Inkonsistente Datentypen: MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY erwartet, BINARY erhalten
```

Sry for the german. Last row means inconsistent Datatypes MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY expected, Binary received.

Is there a way to make this work? It shouldn't include another library than vividsolutions since this is the shape format we get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i finally found the cause. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440496/hibernate-spatial-5-geometrytype) Post from @Paulito.Bandito. Apparently the **versions** for **hibernate-spatial** and **hibernate-commons-annotations** need to be **identical** to be able to persist vividsolution objects (In my case 5.1.2.Final).

I also had to change the entity to:

```
@XmlTransient
@Column(name = "SHAPE")
private MultiPolygon shape;
```